# Elementary geometry triangle problem with equal segments

Tags: geometry

I need help with the following problem.

Given a triangle ABC with known angles $<BAC=\alpha$ and $<ABC=\beta$. M is arbitrary point on AC between A and C. N is a point on BC between B and C such that AM=BN. P is midpoint of MN and Q is midpoint of AB. Find $<PQB$ in terms of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $AB=c$, $AC=b$, $BC=a$, $\vec{AC}=\vec{b}$, $\vec{BC}=\vec{a}$, $\vec{BN}=\frac{x}{a}\vec{a}$ and $\vec{AM}=\frac{x}{b}\vec{b}$.

Hence, $$\vec{QP}=\frac{x}{2ab}(b\vec{a}+a\vec{b}),$$
which says that $QP$ is parallel to bisector of $\angle ACB$.

Thus,
$$\measuredangle PQB=\alpha+\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ}+\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}.$$

Comment: Thanks but why if $AM=xb$  then $BN= xa$?

Comment: And where did the x disappear?

Comment: @OmniaBonaBonis It was my mistake. I fixed my post. See now.

Comment: Why QP is parallel to the bisector, please explain. Thanks

Comment: @OmniaBonaBonis Because $\vec{QP}=\frac{x}{2}\left(\frac{1}{a}\vec{a}+\frac{1}{b}\vec{b}\right)$ and $|\frac{1}{a}\vec{a}|=|\frac{1}{b}\vec{b}|=1$.